NodeJS storing file in memory/disc instead of directly transfering it over to google drive
Using the following code to upload a file to Google Drive. When files over 4-5GB are being transferred, this code continuously starts consuming memory, which then results in an error. I want it to transfer the stream directly to Google Drive so that it will not consume a lot of memory
const createUrlReadStream = (url) => {
    const readable = new Readable({
        read() {}
    });

    get(url, (response) => {
        response.on('data', (chunk) => readable.push(chunk));
        response.on('end', () => readable.push(null));
    }).on('error', (error) => readable.emit('error', error));

    return readable;
};

const createFile = async (mimeType, path, originalname, parent_id) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: getAuthClient() });
            const file = { mimeType, path, originalname };

            var query = "'" + parent_id + "' in parents";

            const list = await drive.files.list({ q: query, fields: 'files(id,name)' });
            const found = list?.data?.files?.find((e) => e.name === originalname);

            if (list?.data?.files?.length > 0 && found) {
                return resolve([found, null]);
            }

            const readable = createUrlReadStream(file.path);

            const { data } = await google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: getAuthClient() }).files.create({
                media: {
                    mimeType: file.mimeType,
                    body: readable
                },
                requestBody: {
                    name: file.originalname,
                    parents: [parent_id || process.env.GOOGLE_ROOT_FOLDER_ID] // Please set the folder ID of created folder in your Google Drive.
                },
                fields: 'id,name'
            });

            resolve([data, null]);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            resolve[(null, err)];
        }
    });
};



I expect this code to transfer a file to Google Drive without storing the entire file's information in the memory or on the file system where the script is running.

About which then results in an error., can you provide the error message? By the way, in the case of files over 4-5GB are beng transferred, how about using the resumable upload? Ref
